# Wordpress: Should this be escaped or not?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, get, escaping

I've recently made a small piece of code extending some of Scribu's Posts to Posts functionality.

What it does is preventing a post to post relation to be set on pages which don't have a specific template.

```
if ( isset( $posttypes_info[ $p2p_binding['from'] ]['only_on'] ) ) {
    if ( ! $_GET['post'] ) return false;

    if ( isset( $posttypes_info[ $p2p_binding['from'] ]['only_on']['template'] ) ) {
        $template = get_post_meta( $_GET['post'], '_wp_page_template', $single = true);
        if ( $template != 'templates/' . $posttypes_info[$p2p_binding['from'] ]['only_on']['template'] . '.php' ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So when editing a post it get the post ID ($_GET['post']) and check if that specific post has the required template. If not it returns false and doesn't set the relation.

wordpress.dev/wp-admin/post.php?**post=2**&action=edit

Now a friend of mine told me I should escape the $_GET['post']. My first thought was that it doesn't set anything with the data retrieved from $_GET['post']. It only checks if it is set, and if it is it tries to get the post meta with it.

So my question is: **should I escape the $_GET['post']? If so why / why not**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you friend is probably talking about is that the contents of `$_GET['post']` may actually have special characters that can not just be included in a valid URL (if you did, it will probably break). To make sure it is valid, it must be URL encoded or "escaped". This may be something as simple as a space (`' '`) which must be encoded as `+` or `%20` in a URL for it to be valid.

Here's a table of special characters that need to be "escaped" (encoded):

http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_url_encoding_table.htm

In PHP, you probably just need to use the `urlencode` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

*EDIT: So summarising the comments that discuss the necessity of "escaping" in the OP's example code above...*

WordPress documentation for `get_post_meta` says the first parameter should be an `int` (number) and thus it should be sufficient to ensure that `$_GET['post']` is really an `int`. Thus in this case, "escaping" (e.g. via `urlencode`) seems unnecessary.

Comment: The only thing I do is retrieve the post param: wordpress.dev/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit

Comment: In your example, you're `post` variable has a value of `2`, which isn't a special character. However, I think your friend is trying to offer you general advice that is applicable whenever you're building a URL.

If you're not building a string that will end up being in a URL, then you are probably fine.

Comment: I'm not building the URL, that has already been done by Wordpress. I just retrieve the parameter `post`.

Comment: I just looked up the documentation for the `get_post_meta` function you're using and it says that the first parameter should always be an `int` (number):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

So you're probably safe. Though in this case, you might want to make sure that `$_GET['post']` is always a number.

Comment: So casting the `$_GET['post']` to `int` would be fine? $id = (int) $_GET['post'].

Comment: Sounds logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if post get param exist you can use.

```
if(isset($_GET['post']))
```

I am not sure I understand question completely. what you mean by "Escape the 
$_GET['post']"

Comment: Yeah, I check if $_GET['post'] is set and if it is I try to retrieve the post meta from that post ID: get_post_meta ( $_GET['post'] ). My friend told me to escape the $_GET['post']. I think he means something like mysqli_real_escape_string() or htmlspecialchars()?

Comment: okay no need to escape anything just make sure value you get is int. I think that will work fine.